# Unable to install pyserial

Tags: python-3.x, pip

PI3B, Buster.
I have installed both python3 and pip3 but when I use pip3 to install pyserial I get a no module error. The wrong directory is being used. How can I fix it please? `volumio@pnbvolumio:~$ sudo python -m pip3 install pyserial /usr/bin/python3: No module named pip3 volumio@pnbvolumio:~$ pip3 --version pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)`

Comment: what does `sudo which python` and `sudo python --version` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pip with sudo is not a good idea.
Read more [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/802544/is-sudo-pip-install-still-a-broken-practice)

Try to install pyserial using this command:

```
python3 -m pip install pyserial
```

You can also try to instal it for current user only:

```
python3 -m pip install pyserial --user
```

Also consider using [virtual environmet](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) to manage multiple environments and hassle free module managing.

Comment: There is no module pip3 installed, only pip. You can use pip3 as a command from bash, but only python3 -m pip.

Comment: Thanks, I am a newbie so feeling my way and I thought I had installed pip3! Your 1st suggestion worked but gave a PATH warning presumably because of where I ran the command, How should I correct that? ```Installing collected packages: pyserial
  The scripts pyserial-miniterm and pyserial-ports are installed in '/home/volumio/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed pyserial-3.5```

Comment: You can set Your PATH with variable: `export PATH=$PATH:/home/volumio/.local/bin`. To add path permanently You should add this line in Your .profile file ~/.bashrc, or ~/.profile. You can read some more [here](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux).

Comment: Thanks Martin. I had found that and used it but unfortunately I still have lots of errors when I run my python code, I think too many inconsistences, I will have to format and start again. It is a struggle as I am trying to get processes written for a PI running Jessie and python2 working under Buster using more recent modules, AND I don't know enough!